# Understanding Warehouse Cache in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Ran two SQL's in Snowflake using sample data.

Query 1:
`select * from  "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF100TCL"."CUSTOMER" where c_birth_day='14' and c_birth_month='7' and c_birth_year='1989'`

Data Pulled from Persisted Storage.

Query 2: Changing filter value. Expectation is since the filters are changed Snowflake would again pull from persistent storage.

`select * from  "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF100TCL"."CUSTOMER" where c_birth_day='15' and c_birth_month='7' and c_birth_year='1989'`

But as per Query Profile it shows 100% scanned from Cache! How is it possible. Does snowflake pull everything out of a table in the warehouse cache irrespective of filters?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Warehouse cache stores the micro-partitions that were used from the first query and leaves them on your warehouse for future queries.  If your next query needs those same micro-partitions to complete its task, it'll use the warehouse cache, rather than fetching the micro-partitions again.

Note that your query shows that your query is using ALL of the micro-partitions, which means neither your first or second query are actually pruning any micro-partitions in your table scan.  The warehouse cache in this instance is a good thing, performance was likely much better than your first query.

It's important to understand that the cache is the entire micro-partitions that were fetched and not just the records that were selected in your first query.